# How to push this array into an 2D array using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array

How can I have `ar2` pushed into `ar1` so as to have them like the Expected Output below?

```
ar1 = 
[
[true,160,"Blusa Crepe Barcelona manga curta",2,"","","",100],
[true,161,"Blusa Crepe Barcelona manga curta",1,"","","",100]
]
```

```
ar2 = ["Concluído",1000]
```

**Expected Output**

```
result = [
[true,160,"Blusa Crepe Barcelona manga curta",2,"","","",100,"Concluído",1000],
[true,161,"Blusa Crepe Barcelona manga curta",1,"","","",100,"Concluído",1000]
]
```

I've tried doing it using a douple `for loop`, but I haven't been able to make it right, as it pushes `ar2` as another array in the outer array:

```
let output= [];
for (let i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < ar1[i].length; j++){
        output.push(ar1[j],ar2)
    }
}
```

Appreaciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concat the array you can use `concat()` method

```js
ar1 = 
[
[true,160,"Blusa Crepe Barcelona manga curta",2,"","","",100],
[true,161,"Blusa Crepe Barcelona manga curta",1,"","","",100]
]
ar2 = ["Concluído",1000]

for(let i = 0; i<ar1.length;i++){
 ar1[i] = ar1[i].concat(ar2)
}

console.log(ar1)
```

For more info on `concat()` please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: Right on! Thank you!